# Highlight qraphql language notepad++

Tags: notepad++

i would like to highlight the keywords of the graphql language in notepadd++. I looked online and found [this](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/689) request on github that point toward [this](https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#SourceCharacter) graphql grammar spec, but i can't understand how to map it into npp. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: `Menu Language >> User Defined Language >> Define your language...`

Comment: i am struggling to understand what to map there..even looking at the graphql spec..am i dumb or is this a bit nasty?

Comment: Well, you need to spend more than few minutes on this. Or search for a theme that supports this, but I doubt there's any. Otherwise, use a more modern and actively developed editor like VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ gives the opportunity to create or add your own Language Syntax Highlighting configuration files. Normally they are to be put in the `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\userDefineLangs`.